# Meaning of "sweaty pastries"

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

In the [New York Times](http://travel.nytimes.com/2010/06/20/travel/20hotels.html),

> An adjacent lounge, called Collage, looks like a modern airport bistro. It serves breakfast by day (a continental spread of **sweaty pastries**), and drinks and bar food by night.

Does *sweaty pastries* sound correct to you?  Could it be a typo for *sweet pastries*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pastries get "sweaty" when the grease in them congeals on the outer surface, giving them the appearance of sweat. The pastries are probably sweet, but I don't think this is a typo, I've seen pastries described as "sweaty" before, usually when they get old or if they are very greasy. These are probably not very good pastries.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how good they were!

Sweet pastries would be nice, sweaty pastries mean they have been sitting there on the counter in hot humid conditions for a couple of days and are less than pleasant.

But my guess since the rest of review is positive that it was a spellchecker gotcha

Comment: Agreed, it’s not a common usage — I would definitely do a double-take at it, and in a different context, I might well assume it was a typo.  But the NYT is usually pretty well-edited, its writers often enjoy being playful with language, and in that paragraph they’re clearly trying to evoke a pretty sketchy atmosphere; so I’d guess it’s deliberate, not a typo.